# Linq return unique records with count of duplicates

Tags: linq, grouping

I have a collection of printed documents:

- orderDetailId,submittedDate,printedCount
- 1,1 Jan 2106,1
- 1,1 Jan 2106,1
- 2,3 Jan 2106,1
- 3,5 Jan 2106,1
- 4,6 Jan 2106,1

I can get all the unique records with:

```
private static IQueryable<OrderFields> GetUniqueJobs(IQueryable<OrderFields> jobs)
{
        IQueryable<OrderFields> uniqueJobs = jobs.GroupBy(x => x.OrderDetailId).Select(group => group.First());<br/>
        return uniqueJobs.OrderBy(x => x.SubmittedDate);
}
```

but I would like the field printedCount to have the number of times each document was printed:

- 1,1 Jan 2106,2
- 2,3 Jan 2106,1
- 3,5 Jan 2106,1
- 4,6 Jan 2106,1

I would be grateful for any help

Thanks for the previous swift answers, but I did not as the question correctly. I can illustrate what I want with some slow ugly code, but this does not actually work ;-)

```
private static List<OrderFields> GetUniqueJobs(IQueryable<OrderFields> jobs)
    {
        Guid lastOrderDetailId = Guid.Empty;
        List<OrderFields> uniqueJobs = new List<OrderFields>();

        jobs = jobs.OrderBy(x => x.OrderDetailId);
        foreach (var job in jobs)
        {
            Guid orderDetailId = job.OrderDetailId;
            if (orderDetailId != lastOrderDetailId)
            {
                uniqueJobs.Add(job);
            }
            else
            {
                uniqueJobs[uniqueJobs.Count - 1].Printed++;
            }
        }
        return uniqueJobs;
    }
```

Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with **Sum** and an **anonymous type**:

```
var result = jobs.GroupBy(x => x.OrderDetailId)
                 .Select(group => new {
                                          // You can take the first if they are equivalent.
                                          Value = group.First(),
                                          PrintedCount = group.Sum(g => g.PrintedCount)
                                      });
```

Comment: Count is wrong in this context. You have to use Sum to get the right number of printed documents. And you don't have to group by SubmittedDate.

Comment: @Julia thanks, I didn't pay attention at PrintedCount column.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    var uniqueJobs = jobs.GroupBy(x => new {x.orderDetailId, x.submittedDate})
                         .Select(group => new
                         {
                                orderDetailId = x.Key.orderDetailId,
                                submittedDate = x.Key.submittedDate,
                                printedCount = x.Sum(i => i.printedCount) // Or Count() I dont know your values.
                         });
    return uniqueJobs.OrderBy(x => x.SubmittedDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use  IEnumerable< KeyValuePair < int,int>>:

```
private static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int,int>> GetUniqueJobs(IQueryable jobs)
{
    var uniqueJobs = jobs.GroupBy(x => x.OrderDetailId).Select(group => new KeyValuePair<int, int>(group.Key, group.Sum(x => x.printedCount))).OrderBy(x => x.Key);
    return uniqueJobs;
}
```

Or to use an AnonymusType:

```
var uniqueJobs = jobs.GroupBy(x => x.OrderDetailId).Select(group => new {OrderDetailId = group.Key, printedCount = group.Sum(x => x.printedCount)});
```